# Java UUID not being recognised after conversion to string

Tags: java, uuid

During the course of my programming I noticed the following behaviour. I would expect this code segment to print "They are equal" instead it prints "They are not equal", could anyone please explain this behaviour? Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    UUID originalUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    String string     = originalUUID.toString();
    UUID copiedUUID   = UUID.fromString(string);
    System.out.println("Original: " + originalUUID);
    System.out.println("Copy    : " + copiedUUID);
    if(originalUUID == copiedUUID){
        System.out.println("They are equal");
    }else{
        System.out.println("They are not equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue. However, these aren't strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The == operator tests that the two references point to the same object -- not whether the two objects are equal.

If you want to test for object equality, use the equals() method, which is defined by the UUID class.

```
 if ( originalUUID.equals( copiedUUID )) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your "==" to the following:

```
if(originalUUID.equals(copiedUUID)){
.
.
```